# Can Oracle Golden Gate replicate stored proc definition changes also?

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I have setup Oracle Golden Gate Table Data & DDL replication successfully (Unidirectional)

Now, I want all my stored proc definition changes also be replicated, can that be done.

Since in my Extract param file in source I have added explicitly tables to be replicated can I add a proc name there to be replicated? if yes How?

Source Extract param file:
EXTRACT EXTORA
USERID C##GGADMIN, PASSWORD ggadmin
RMTHOST 10.0.0.5, MGRPORT 7809
RMTTRAIL ./dirdat/rt
DDL INCLUDE MAPPED
DDLOPTIONS REPORT
LOGALLSUPCOLS
UPDATERECORDFORMAT COMPACT
TABLE pdb1.test.TCUSTMER;
TABLE pdb1.test.TCUSTORD;

Destination Replicat param file:
REPLICAT REPORA
ASSUMETARGETDEFS
DISCARDFILE ./dirrpt/repora.dsc, PURGE, MEGABYTES 100
DDL INCLUDE MAPPED
DDLOPTIONS REPORT
DBOPTIONS INTEGRATEDPARAMS(parallelism 6)
USERID repuser@pdb1, PASSWORD rep_pass
MAP pdb1.test.*, TARGET pdb1.test.*;

Comment: Please [refer](https://www.vitalsofttech.com/configure-goldengate-ddl-replication/) to this link for Databases 12c above  use parameter `DDL INCLUDE MAPPED` on both extract and replicat for other databases first you need to set up ddl replication and enable

Comment: I have this configuration already enabled, my doubt is since I have mentioned two tables explicitly will it replicate the schema changes for any procs as well. For mentioned tables it is replicating the table schema changes what about programmable object changes which I make? 

Question edited with extract and replicat param files.

Answer (score 0):

Then a DDL INCLUDE ALL needs to be added in Extract and replicat.